# Setting up two-machine kernel debugging via firewire

Tags: macos, debugging, remote-debugging, kernel

The instructions found at [Setting Up Kernel Debugging](http://fieldofcows.com/index.php?title=Setting_up_Kernel_Debugging_on_OS_X) are what I used to get to this point. On the machine running the kext I want to debug, I do see the message "Connected to remote debugger". On the machine I am running gdb on, I do see:

```
(gdb) kdp-reattach localhost
Connected.
```

The problem is that 'showallkmods' returns an empty list and none of the other similar commands appear to be working:

```
(gdb) showallkmods
kmod        address     size        id    refs     version  name

(gdb) showalltasks
task        vm_map      ipc_space  #acts   pid  process     io_policy    wq_state   command
Invalid type combination in equality test.

(gdb) showregistry
Please load kgmacros after KDP attaching to the target.

(gdb) source /Volumes/KernelDebugKit/kgmacros 
Loading Kernel GDB Macros package.  Type "help kgm" for more info.

(gdb) showallkmods
kmod        address     size        id    refs     version  name

(gdb) showregistry
Please load kgmacros after KDP attaching to the target.

(gdb) showbootargs
Invalid cast.
```

I am running 10.6.8 and am using kernel_debug_kit_10.6.8_10k540.dmg

I am not sure what other details one might need to diagnose what has gone wrong, but if you want to ask questions in the comments, I can certainly attempt to provide additional details.

Answer (score 1):

The error "`Invalid type combination in equality test.`" indicates to me that gdb might be expecting a different CPU architecture than the kernel you're connecting to is running. The 10.6 kernel exists in both 32-bit and 64-bit variants, and by default it's determined by the hardware which one gets loaded. gdb normally defaults to x86_64 if your CPU supports it (true of all Intel Macs except the very early Core Duo based ones) so if you're connecting to a 32-bit kernel (the default on most Macs released before 2011) you need to pass the `-arch i386` argument when starting gdb. You can check the current kernel CPU architecture by running the `uname -a` command.

**Update:** on OSX Mountain Lion, the kernel always runs in 64-bit (x86_64) mode. On OSX *Lion*, the kernel defaults to 64-bit mode on Macs which are *capable* of running *Mountain Lion* and in 32-bit mode otherwise.